# How do I access data stored on a hidden drive partition from a C# application

Tags: c#

I am looking to create a .NET application that accesses data stored on a hidden drive partition.

Does anyone know of a way of achieving this?

Comment: You can see it from Computer Management->Disk Management. I want to access it without assigning it a drive letter